# Passing pointers between functions in an implementation of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

The problem was solved. A guy gave it in comments. The problem was that I was using `%d` to read in a `short int`. I should have used `%hd` or I should have used an `int'.

---

I tried to create a program of singly-linked list **using only local variables**. I was able to make a working program by using global variables.

The program with local variables compiles but it crashes when I try to traverse the linked list.

I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with the implementation with local variables. What is the problem present in the Implementation with local variables?

ABOUT THE STRUCTURE OF THE PROGRAMS:

I understand that the programs are big so I'll put in something about structure of the program.

- The program is structured as a menu driven program. So the initial calls to functions are in main() function
- There are 3 options in main() menu - exit, traverse and insertion
- Exit returns 0 to exit program while other 2 do function calls
- Insertion function itself is arranged as menu-driven program.
- It has 3 options - return , insert_begin and insert_end. The last 2 are function calls.
- I know there are memory leaks as I haven't freed any memory but I will take care of that after I can understand the problem in the current program.

//WORKING IMPLEMENTATION USING GLOBAL VARIABLE

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 2

#define INS_MIN 0
#define INS_MAX 2

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}sll_node;

sll_node *start = NULL;

void intro()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\tThese are the various options:\n");
    printf("\n\t00 Exit");
    printf("\n\t01 Traverse the list");
    printf("\n\t02 Insertion into the list");
}

void insert_begin()
{
    sll_node *node = malloc(sizeof(sll_node));
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\tNot enough menory");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int data;
    printf("\n\tData to be entered: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);

    node->data = data;
    node-> next = start;
    start = node;
}

void insert_end()
{
    sll_node *node = malloc(sizeof(sll_node));
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\tNot enough menory");
        exit(-2);
    }

    if(start == NULL)
        insert_begin();
    else
    {
        printf("\n\tData to be entered: ");
        scanf("%d", &(node->data));
        node-> next = NULL;

        sll_node *node2;
        for(node2 = start; node2->next != NULL; node2 = node2->next)
            ;
        node2->next = node;
    }
}

void insert_intro()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\tThese are the various options:\n");
    printf("\n\t00 Insertion Done");
    printf("\n\t01 Insert at beginning");
    printf("\n\t02 Insert at end");
}

void insertion()
{
    short choice;
    while(1)
    {
        choice = -1;
        while(choice < INS_MIN || choice > INS_MAX)
        {
            insert_intro();
            printf("\n\n\tEnter your chocie: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 0:
            return;
        case 1:
            insert_begin();
            break;
        case 2:
            insert_end();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void traverse()
{
    if(start == NULL)
        printf("\n\n\tLinked list is empty");
    else
    {
        printf("\n\n\t");
        for(sll_node *node = start; node != NULL; node = node->next)
            printf("%d ", node->data);
    }
    getch();
}

int main()
{
    short choice;
    while(1)
    {
        choice = -1;
        while(choice < MIN || choice > MAX)
        {
            intro();
            printf("\n\n\tEnter your choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        case 1:
            traverse();
            break;
        case 2:
            insertion();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

//COMPILES BUT CRASHES - Same program but with local variable start and variable passing between functions

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 2

#define INS_MIN 0
#define INS_MAX 2

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}sll_node;

void intro()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\tThese are the various options:\n");
    printf("\n\t00 Exit");
    printf("\n\t01 Traverse the list");
    printf("\n\t02 Insertion into the list");
}

sll_node* insert_begin(sll_node *start)
{
    sll_node *node = malloc(sizeof(sll_node));
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\tNot enough menory");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int data;
    printf("\n\tData to be entered: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);

    node->data = data;
    node-> next = start;
    return node;
}

sll_node* insert_end(sll_node *start)
{
    sll_node *node = malloc(sizeof(sll_node));
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\tNot enough menory");
        exit(-2);
    }

    if(start == NULL)
        start = insert_begin(start);
    else
    {
        printf("\n\tData to be entered: ");
        scanf("%d", &(node->data));
        node-> next = NULL;

        sll_node *node2;
        for(node2 = start; node2->next != NULL; node2 = node2->next)
            ;
        node2->next = node;
    }
    return start;
}

void insert_intro()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\tThese are the various options:\n");
    printf("\n\t00 Insertion Done");
    printf("\n\t01 Insert at beginning");
    printf("\n\t02 Insert at end");
}

sll_node* insertion(sll_node *start)
{
    short choice;
    while(1)
    {
        choice = -1;
        while(choice < INS_MIN || choice > INS_MAX)
        {
            insert_intro();
            printf("\n\n\tEnter your chocie: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 0:
            return start;
        case 1:
            start = insert_begin(start);
            break;
        case 2:
            start = insert_end(start);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void traverse(sll_node *start)
{
    if(start == NULL)
        printf("\n\n\tLinked list is empty");
    else
    {
        printf("\n\n\t");
        for(sll_node *node = start; node != NULL; node = node->next)
            printf("%d ", node->data);
    }
    getch();
}

int main()
{
    sll_node *start = NULL;
    short choice;
    while(1)
    {
        choice = -1;
        while(choice < MIN || choice > MAX)
        {
            intro();
            printf("\n\n\tEnter your choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        case 1:
            traverse(start);
            break;
        case 2:
            start = insertion(start);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you also show how `insert_begin` is called and how `start` is used!

Comment: @zaphod These are complete programs that compile. You'll have to scroll a little. The call to insert_begin and insert_end is present in function insertion().

Comment: oops my bad! didn't note the scrollbar!

Comment: change `short choice` to `int choice`

Comment: @TaylorFlores How does this can have any effect on the traversal? Correct functions are being called even when I am using short instead of int.

Comment: @Zel I didn't say it affected your traversal. If `printf` expects an `int`, however, and you've given it a `short`, there's a remote chance you could cause a segmentation fault (it's common that `int` is much larger than `short`). That's why I said change it to `int` (or change `%d` to `%h`)

Comment: @TaylorFlores I had no idea that there were format sub-specifier in existence. The correct thing is `%hd` instead of `%h`. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept your answer. It solved the whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `short choice` to `int choice`.

Why does this make a difference?

Short answer is that `printf("%d")` expects an integer.

The long answer is `"%d"` describes the data type you are passing to `printf` as an integer (which is commonly 4 to 8 bytes), and you're giving it a datatype of `short` - which is commonly 2 bytes long. When your program reads the input and stores it at the pointer, `&choice`, it writes 4 bytes starting at that address (but only 2 were reserved). This causes a segmentation fault and will crash your program.

Here's a [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) to some `printf` documentation. You'll notice that to pass a `short` to `printf` you would write `%hd` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything from `insertion()` function when item is added to a list. So linked list may not get constructed properly.

Probably, you should return `start` only when its added at the beginning, otherwise `start` in `main()` will not point to head of the list.

```
sll_node* insertion(sll_node *start)
{
        ...
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 0:
            return start;
        case 1:
            start = insert_begin(start);
            return start;  //<----- return node
            break;
        case 2:
            start = insert_end(start);
            break;
        }
    ...

}
```

Comment: I'll have to return in the case when I insert at end. What about the case when the list is empty and the function is called for insertion at end? The end is beginning and hence I'll have to return some value. The function insert at end actually returns the start so there should be no problem if I return start.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions before and after your edit. Program still crashes during traversal.

Comment: @Zel, yes, you would handle case appropriately when first node is added at the end.

Comment: @Rohan Didn't get your last comment. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: @Zel, It will be helpful if you write steps (how did you insert nodes, choices that used) etc, when you get crash. Update that in question.

Comment: The problem got solved. @TaylorFlores gave the answer in a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

When i compile your code on my computer, it works, but i changed "short choice" to "int choice", because scanf("%d", &choice) takes 4 bytes to write on, and when choice is short it crashes, because short has only 2 bytes, therefore stack corruption will occur, my be on your computer this corruption damage the "start" pointer.

Comment: I beat you to this in a comment ;)

Comment: Depends on compiler: some will take scanf("%hd", &shortvariable)

Comment: Your suggestion works but @TaylorFlores told it first. Your explanatin helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About the crash. Change the argument **start** in both functions **insert_begin** and **insert_end** to **sll_node ** start**, and when assigning new value, use the expression ***start = *your-new-value***. It is because you have to pass a pointer to the local variable **start** which is also pointer. You do not need to change function **traverse**.

About memory leaks, let me to point-out that when you call **insert_begin** from inside **insert_end**, the node created from **insert_end** is left unused. before **exit()** and the **return** in main() you should free the list.

Comment: I had actually tried that also. It doesn't work either. I found the solution. TaylorFlores gave it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry. There was another bug hard to see. It was at 2 lines where you read (choice).

```
    short choice;
    ...
    // It is ERROR to use "%d" with (short choice), because the stack will
    // be overwritten with unsuspected results. The format specifier "%hd"
    // say to compiler that (&choice) point to a short 16-bit integer,
    // not 32-bit
    scanf("%hd", &choice);
```

This is slightly different version, tested, without memory leaks.

```
//

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    #define MIN 0
    #define MAX 2
    #define INS_MIN 0
    #define INS_MAX 2

    typedef struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    } sll_node;

    void clear_list(sll_node** start)
    {
        assert(start != NULL);
        sll_node* node = *start;
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            sll_node* element = node;
            node = element->next;
            free(element);
        }
        *start = NULL;
    }

    void intro()
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\tThese are the various options:\n");
        printf("\n\t00 Exit");
        printf("\n\t01 Traverse the list");
        printf("\n\t02 Insertion into the list");
    }

    void insert_begin(sll_node** pstart)
    {
        sll_node* node = (sll_node*)malloc(sizeof(sll_node));
        if (node == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\tNot enough menory");
            clear_list(pstart);
            exit(-1);
        }
        int data;
        printf("\n\tData to be entered: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &data);//scanf
        node->data = data;
        node->next = *pstart;
        // update the local variable start passed from main to point just inserted node
        *pstart = node;
    }

    void insert_end(sll_node** start)
    {
        assert(start != NULL);
        if (*start == NULL)
        {
            insert_begin(start);
        }
        else
        {
            sll_node* node = (sll_node*)malloc(sizeof(sll_node));
            if (node == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n\tNot enough menory");
                clear_list(start);
                exit(-2);
            }
            printf("\n\tData to be entered: ");
            scanf("%d", &(node->data));
            node->next = NULL;
            sll_node* node2;
            for(node2 = *start; node2->next != NULL; node2 = node2->next)
                ;
            node2->next = node;
        }
    }

    void insert_intro()
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\tThese are the various options:\n");
        printf("\n\t00 Insertion Done");
        printf("\n\t01 Insert at beginning");
        printf("\n\t02 Insert at end");
    }

    void insertion(sll_node** start)
    {
        short choice;
        while(1)
        {
            choice = -1;
            while(choice < INS_MIN || choice > INS_MAX)
            {
                insert_intro();
                printf("\n\n\tEnter your chocie: ");
                scanf("%hd", &choice);
            }
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 0:
                return;
            case 1:
                insert_begin(start);
                break;
            case 2:
                insert_end(start);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void traverse(sll_node *start)
    {
        if (start == NULL)
            printf("\n\n\tLinked list is empty");
        else
        {
            printf("\n\n\t");
            for(sll_node *node = start; node != NULL; node = node->next)
                printf("%d ", node->data);
        }
        getch();
    }

    int main()
    {
        sll_node *start = NULL;
        short choice;
        while(1)
        {
            choice = -1;
            while(choice < MIN || choice > MAX)
            {
                intro();
                printf("\n\n\tEnter your choice: ");
                scanf("%hd", &choice);
            }
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 0:
                clear_list(&start);
                return 0;
            case 1:
                traverse(start);
                break;
            case 2:
                insertion(&start);
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

P.S. Very hard to edit! I'm new here and do not have enough experience. Wasted a lot of time to edit!

Comment: Best way to edit code is to go to an IDE -> edit -> then replace the original code. Editing on SO is a hassle